# How to use sort_keys in Python CalDAV?

Tags: python, caldav

The Python CalDAV documentation says one can search calendars and sort result by sort_keys. But I cannot find any hint, what these keys could be.

> search(xml=None, comp_class=None, todo=None, include_completed=False, sort_keys=(), split_expanded=True, **kwargs)